# I can not integrate mautic with sendgrid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, sendgrid, mautic

can not integrate mautic with sendgrid, show me this error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net 
>   [Connection timed out #110] Log data: ++ Starting
>   Mautic\EmailBundle\Swiftmailer\Transport\SendgridTransport !!
>   Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net 
>   [Connection timed out #110] (code: 0)
>   ++ Starting Mautic\EmailBundle\Swiftmailer\Transport\SendgridTransp

I installed mautic on googlecloud. 
I configured the mautic correctly with the data from sendgrid but can not send the email what should I do? Changed firewall rules on the google cloud vpc network

Answer (score 0):

On GCE to connect to sendgrid you will need to use port 2525 as outbound connections on other email ports are blocked.

Comment: Do I change at this point? "bitnami-default-ports"
Because I changed some firewall rules and did not solve